# assign with $ R

Tags: r, get, assign

I have several vector describing a trip, in each of them there are indications of latitude and longitude.

The code I am trying to write is the following

```
for (i in 1:ntrips){
 for (k in 1:dim(get(paste0("trip",i)))[1]){

 assign(paste0("trip", i)$distance[k],gcd.hf(get(paste0("trip", i))$long.start[k],get(paste0("trip",i))$lat.start[k],get(paste0("trip",i))$end.start[k],get(paste0("trip", i))$lat.end[k]))

 }
}
```

Basically for each vector (trip1, trip2, ...), I want to calculate the value of the distance with the function gcd.hf (defined previously) and paste it in the column named distance.

the error I get is

```
Error: $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors
```

Is there anything I am missing?

Comment: if trip1, trip2.. are vectors then you can't use the $ operator. Are they data.frames or atomic vectors?

Comment: they are data.frame

Comment: You should not be (mis)using `assign` and `get`. Put your `trip*` variables into a list and iterate over the list.

Comment: how can I do that?

Comment: `my_list <- mget(x = paste0("trip",1:ntrips))` presumably. Once you have them in a list, use tools like `lapply`. `assign` and `get` should be avoided unless you already know enough about them to feel a little bad just considering using them.

Comment: Not enough code to create an example that can be run, tested, and debugged.

Answer (score -1):

The very first part of assign is not legitimate

```
 paste0("trip", i)$distance[k]
```

Try using legitimate names for your variables. E.g.
inside the loop

```
ma_trip<-get(paste0("trip",i))
assign(paste0("trip", i,"_distance",ma_trip$distance[k]),...)
```

## ADDITION

So let's begin from scratch:

Create the trips along with the coordinates:

```
fac<-100
N<-3#number of trips
for(i in 1:N){#create N data.tables
  for(j in round(max(runif(3)*10),0)){#with random number of rows
    #the coordinates are generated 
    long.start<-fac*runif(j)
    long.end<-fac*runif(j)
    lat.start<-fac*runif(j)
    lat.end<-fac*runif(j)
  }
assign(paste0("trip",i),data.table(long.start,long.end,lat.start,lat.end))#and are attributed to the data.table
}
```

Each data.table has the following form:

```
 >trip1

    long.start long.end lat.start  lat.end
 1:   89.18974 98.44804  34.68381 62.55508
 2:   55.95637 95.27552  23.33369 75.74160
 3:   59.32357 73.49386  12.62365 50.18466
 4:   81.72157 20.00639  40.20866 93.14260
 5:   18.08152 52.52404  88.42411 19.10752
 6:   54.50308 91.24726  27.19433 80.65325
 7:   73.17393 19.83704  60.40830 23.68220
 8:   77.57680 87.32211  76.25292 12.22423
 9:   93.60303 55.62256  95.20154 32.75852
```

The dimension of the `tripN` objects can be given by

```
 >lapply(lapply(ls(pattern = "^trip"),get),dim)
[[1]]
[1] 9 4

[[2]]
[1] 9 4

[[3]]
[1] 10  4
```

In order to retrieve the coordinates and calculate distances (per row for each data.table):

```
ntrips<-length(ls(pattern = "^trip"))#dynamically

for(i in 1:ntrips){
  da_trip<-get(paste0("trip",i))
  distance<-NULL
  for(k in 1:dim(da_trip)[1]){
    distance[k]<-gcd.hf(long1 =as.numeric(da_trip[,.(long.start)][k]),long2=as.numeric(da_trip[,.(long.end)][k]),lat1 = as.numeric(da_trip[,.(lat.start)][k]),lat2=as.numeric(da_trip[,.(lat.end)][k]))
  }
 assign(paste0("trip",i),cbind(da_trip,distance)) # send the distance to the initial data table as column
}
```

resulting in :

```
>trip1
   long.start long.end lat.start  lat.end  distance
 1:   89.18974 98.44804  34.68381 62.55508  1413.027
 2:   55.95637 95.27552  23.33369 75.74160 12065.602
 3:   59.32357 73.49386  12.62365 50.18466 10247.026
 4:   81.72157 20.00639  40.20866 93.14260 14830.970
 5:   18.08152 52.52404  88.42411 19.10752 15388.778
 6:   54.50308 91.24726  27.19433 80.65325 17081.717
 7:   73.17393 19.83704  60.40830 23.68220  4668.884
 8:   77.57680 87.32211  76.25292 12.22423 16361.216  
 9:   93.60303 55.62256  95.20154 32.75852  2562.363
```

Also the new dimensions of all the trip objects:

```
 lapply(lapply(ls(pattern = "^trip"),get),dim)
[[1]]
[1] 9 5

[[2]]
[1] 9 5

[[3]]
[1] 10  5
```

## DATA TABLE way

In `data.table` instead of loop you can always perform operations between columns as shown below:

`trip1[,distance2:=gcd.hf(long.start,lat.start,long.end,lat.end),by=1:nrow(trip1)]`

```
> trip1
   long.start long.end lat.start  lat.end  distance distance2
1:   89.18974 98.44804  34.68381 62.55508  1413.027  1413.027
2:   55.95637 95.27552  23.33369 75.74160 12065.602 12065.602
                               [...]
```

Comment: The problem is that distance is a vector within the data.frame trip

Comment: I think I understood the whole issue here. Check the updated code out!